# How to instantiate a Class object for a parameterized class using reflection and Guava TypeToken

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guava

I'm trying to pull off some Guava `TypeToken` magic for a class which is parameterized with a generic type parameter, but I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to instantiate it through the `Class.forName(String)` method.

```
public class EnumeratedMenu<E extends Enum<E>,T extends EnumeratedBean<E>> {

    private final TypeToken<EnumeratedMenu<E,T>> typeToken =
            new TypeToken<EnumeratedMenu<E,T>>(getClass()) { };

    private Class<T> getBean() {

        TypeToken<?> genericBeanParam = typeToken.resolveType(EnumeratedMenu.class.getTypeParameters()[1]);

        try {
            //This generates a ClassNotFoundException because of the generic type parameter that EnumeratedBean has.
            return (Class<T>)Class.forName(genericBeanParam.getType().getTypeName());
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("Unable to find the class definition for {}", genericBeanParam.getType().getTypeName());
            log.catching(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this exception:

"Unable to find the class definition for `EnumeratedBean<ContextMenuOption$ContextType>`"

`ContextMenuOption$ContextType` is the runtime type of the generic `enum` parameter for `EnumeratedBean`. How do I get the class object I want?

Clarification:

I need to construct and instance of the class to use with a builder object that will construct a menu option like this below:

```
T optionBean = beanFactory.create(beanClass);

IEnumeratedMenuOptionBuilder<E,T> builder = new EnumeratedMenuOptionBuilder<>(optionBean);
builder.setDriver(getDriver()).setTimeoutInSeconds(getTimeoutInSeconds())
        .setEnumerationFunction(getEnumerationFunction());
```

Comment: TypeToken.of(getClass()).resolveType(EnumeratedMenu.class.getTypeParameters()[1]).getRawType() should give you raw class to instantiate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to do, as there is always just one single `Class`, regardless of parameterizations. This is how Java generics work with type erasure.
For detailed explanation of how and why, you may want to read:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html

But as to instantiation you will simply need to use the `Class` you already have; and cast generic type signature the way you want.

This means, for example, that you can actually do:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> numbers = (List<Integer>)(List<?>) strings;
numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(12));
```

without runtime exceptions. There is no real runtime information limiting contents; only implicit casting. You would, however, get a runtime exception if you tried:

```
String str = strings.get(0);
```

because while underlying `List` happily accepts any `java.lang.Object`s, access code has "hidden" cast, which will trigger exception.

So, instantiation may work something like:

```
List<String> s = (List<String>) ArrayList.class.newInstance();
```

but using whatever generic type you want.

EDIT:

And if Guava's `TypeToken` is needed, its javadocs suggest you should either get raw class with `getRawType()`, or perhaps directly create instance with `constructor()`.

Comment: Thanks. This put me on the right track to getting this to work.

Answer (score 4):

What are you actually trying to do here?

You're never going to be able to get a `Class<T>` object that represents a generic type like `EnumeratedBean<ContextMenuOption$ContextType>`, because `Class` can only represent a raw type like `EnumeratedBean`.

It's possible that there's some other way to achieve the result you want, but it's not clear what that result you want is currently. For example, what do you want to use the `Class` you're returning for? Perhaps it's possible to do *that* without the intermediate `Class` object.

**Edit:**

Since it looks like what you wanted was to be able to create an instance of `T`, here's an example of how you could do it using `TypeToken`:

```
public class EnumeratedMenu<E extends Enum<E>, T extends EnumeratedBean<E>> {

  // Just get the type of T, that's what we care about here
  private final TypeToken<T> typeToken = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};

  private T create() {
    try {
      // Using the raw type Class object for the token to
      // get at its default constructor.
      return typeToken.constructor(typeToken.getRawType().getConstructor())
          .invoke(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to instantiate the object as a parameterized type and set its fields using a builder class that will user the values in the bean's fields to construct a menu option.

Comment: @Selena Underlying `Class` object never varies between generic types: actual `Class` for, say, `List<String>` is exactly the same as that of `List<Integer>` (feel free to test this to verify that actual `Class` object you get via `list.getClass()` is same). This also means that instantiation via reflection is exactly the same; much of generic types are handled by compiler inserting casts, and there is no real runtime difference. This means that you will not be able to construct different classes: they do not exist. You will rather need to use the existing type-erased `Class`.

Comment: @StaxMan: Okay. So how do I get an instance of the type-erased class from the Guava type token?

Comment: Looking at `TypeToken` javadocs, I am guessing "getRawType()"; although maybe you could just use "constructor()" to be able to instantiate type passed?

Comment: @StaxMan: Thanks. This is what I needed. So, you should add this detail to your answer below because it's an important part of the solution to getting this to work with TypeToken.

Comment: Added an example of creating an instance of `T` using `TypeToken`. @StaxMan is right that for the purposes of instantiation, the raw `Class` is all you need.